# Finding all the possible IP addresses, running into infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, recursion

This is a problem where you have to enter a number having non zero digits and the program will convert it into a IP address having 4 parts and each part less than 255, and have to print all the IP addresses.
I have tried this recursive method and am running into an infinite loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int a[3];
void comuni(unsigned long n,int count){
    int i=count;
    do{
        if(count<0){
            return;
        }
        int t=pow(10,i);
        a[count]=n/t;
        int rem=n%t;
        if(a[count]<=255 &&a[count]>0 && count>=0){
            printf("%d.",a[count]);
            comuni(rem,count-1);
        }    
        i++;
    }while(1);
}

int main()
{
    //  Insert your code here.
    unsigned long n;
    scanf("%ul",&n);
    comuni(n,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by all the ip addresses? Can you give examples?

Comment: Why are you dividing by 10? If these are parts of an IP address, you should be dividing by 256.

Comment: `int a[3];` creates an array with enough space for **three** values: `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`. You try to access `a[3]` which does not exist!

Comment: Ayush Gupta, please let me know how I can make my answer more helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is why there is an infinite loop.

Starting with a look at `while(1)` it does not surprise me.
But wait, there is a `return` inside, which is used if `count` is less than 0.
Nothing inside the loop changes `count`. So if `count` is greater or equal 0 to begin with you got your infinite loop.

I think the problem which causes that situation is that this

```
int i=count;
```

does NOT cause `count` to change when you change `i`.
You do change `i` inside the loop, but you know - it does not help.

Comment: I think I want to offer a bounty on the head of teachers who promote the use of `while(1)` under any circumstance...

Comment: What about embedded real-time system use?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That is my trade. Expected uptime measured in decades. I considered mentioning it. But you are right. In exactly that environment I have seen one `while(1)` in not more than 19 years work. There are exceptions to any rule. But looking at SO newbie questions, there is no excuse. Should I mention that loop then at least had the decency to not contain any `break` or `return`? When I write `while(1)` I mean it.

Comment: Is there a conventional alternative for the main loop?  My embedded experience was from back in my College days and we were mostly left to our own devices to figure out how to implement projects outside of specific topics usually pertaining to MCU registers and IO and the like.

Comment: Nowadays (and for 19 years, in an industry which is usually considered "behind" by 10 to 20 years) embedded systems use dedicated, highly targeted operating systems. Yes, implementing one of those might contain another endless loop, which then however also does not have break/returns inside. Any loop with either can better (as in maintainable, readable, debuggable, ...) have a condition which reflects when the loop is to be left. The OS I was using does contain a condition and when it is not met anymore goes for shutdown/reset - in case of unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons We are wandering off-topic here. Would you like to turn that into a question? I probably would refrain from answering however. While I enjoy ranting here, I am not sure that I can give a universally accepted answer... If you ask, try to avoid the "opinionated" close-vote reason.

Comment: Perhaps the disconnect there may be that my embedded experience was on a platform without an OS; just programming the bare metal. And the main loops we were working with weren't ever supposed to exit: run until power is removed.  I'll ponder over whether a decent on-topic question can be made out of this thread.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Keep in mind that `while(1)` loops which do NOT have either `break` or `return` inside are fine with me. If you truly mean an endless loop, then program like that. But for "loop forever and ever until the universe ends, except if somewhere in the middle I change my mind" any programmer deserves all the debugging necessity they harvest...